# Why can you not look through glass?

Tags: optics, glass

I have this table but I cannot find out why I cannot look through the side of it.

Comment: Could not post a picture og the glass, but the glass is all green at the end

Comment: Related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607574/).